# DevExpress DateTime Picker

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, datetimepicker

I am using DevExpress with C# .net. Can see Date Picker, and Time picker controls separately. Is there any control for DateTime in Single DropDown selection ?

Comment: Vendors like DevExpress do try to avoid re-inventing controls that are already available in .NET.  Like DateTimePicker.

Comment: This is not available in .Net the DateTimePicker is a Date *OR* Time picker, not both.

Answer (score 5):

To edit the time in the editor, set its `DisplayFormat` and `EditFormat` properties to DateTime format strings that include times.

To show the time in the dropdown, set the `DateTimeEdit`'s [`VistaDisplayMode`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemDateEdit_VistaDisplayModetopic) and [`VistaEditTime`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemDateEdit_VistaEditTimetopic) properties to `True`.

Comment: On how to set two properties?  See also http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItem_EditFormattopic

Comment: The VistaEditTime property is only available at code level. If you try to set this property with the help of the Designer look for **CalendarTimeEditing** and set that property to True.

Comment: @Sascha: See the docs; `This property is obsolete. Use the CalendarView property instead.`